# Center align text within specific area (rectangle) with Imagemagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I need to center align text within a rectangle. It is a composition so we have a background, logo and text.

Here is the code:

```
$file = 'filename_'.rand(5,15).'.gif';

exec("convert 'images/highres/bg/deer_and_snow_blue.gif' -coalesce -interline-spacing 2 -font fonts/FredokaOneRegular.ttf -fill black -pointsize 16 -annotate +220+520 \"This is some sample text here \" null: \( 'images/uploads/cganewlogored.jpeg' -resize 165.34736842105264x84 -coalesce \) -geometry +666.652631579+501 -layers Composite " . $file);

echo '<img src="'.$file.'" />';
```

I have an example here of a text aligned version which is fine (image 2). But, i need it to move to the green area (image 2)

Image 1:
[image]

Image 2:
[image]

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Hi @MarcB As you can see from Image 1 the text is in the middle of the image and not the center of the green area. Furthermore, the text runs full width rather than a set width.